# Having an error with RefreshController in SmartRefresher in flutter?

Tags: flutter

[image]

I get the error when I pull the the screen at the end of it but when I do it , I get error .I don't have no idea why I get this error. Please help me .

Here is my food_const.dart file's code,

import 'package:lecture_7/model/food_model.dart';

```
List<FoodModel> FOODLIST = <FoodModel>[
  FoodModel("Burgar", "KFC", "images/food2.jpg", 2.99),
  FoodModel("Chenese Dip", "Hawkers", "images/sushi.jpg", 4.99),
  FoodModel("Burgar", "KFC", "images/food2.jpg", 2.99),
  FoodModel("Chenese Dip", "Hawkers", "images/sushi.jpg", 4.99),
  FoodModel("Burgar", "KFC", "images/food2.jpg", 2.99),
    FoodModel("Burgar", "KFC", "images/food2.jpg", 2.99),
  FoodModel("Chenese Dip", "Hawkers", "images/sushi.jpg", 4.99),
  FoodModel("Burgar", "KFC", "images/food2.jpg", 2.99),
  FoodModel("Chenese Dip", "Hawkers", "images/sushi.jpg", 4.99),
  FoodModel("Burgar", "KFC", "images/food2.jpg", 2.99),
    FoodModel("Burgar", "KFC", "images/food2.jpg", 2.99),
  FoodModel("Chenese Dip", "Hawkers", "images/sushi.jpg", 4.99),
  FoodModel("Burgar", "KFC", "images/food2.jpg", 2.99),
  FoodModel("Chenese Dip", "Hawkers", "images/sushi.jpg", 4.99),
  FoodModel("Burgar", "KFC", "images/food2.jpg", 2.99),
    FoodModel("Burgar", "KFC", "images/food2.jpg", 2.99),
  FoodModel("Chenese Dip", "Hawkers", "images/sushi.jpg", 4.99),
  FoodModel("Burgar", "KFC", "images/food2.jpg", 2.99),
  FoodModel("Chenese Dip", "Hawkers", "images/sushi.jpg", 4.99),
  FoodModel("Burgar", "KFC", "images/food2.jpg", 2.99),
    FoodModel("Burgar", "KFC", "images/food2.jpg", 2.99),
  FoodModel("Chenese Dip", "Hawkers", "images/sushi.jpg", 4.99),
  FoodModel("Burgar", "KFC", "images/food2.jpg", 2.99),
  FoodModel("Chenese Dip", "Hawkers", "images/sushi.jpg", 4.99),
  FoodModel("Burgar", "KFC", "images/food2.jpg", 2.99),
    FoodModel("Burgar", "KFC", "images/food2.jpg", 2.99),
  FoodModel("Chenese Dip", "Hawkers", "images/sushi.jpg", 4.99),
  FoodModel("Burgar", "KFC", "images/food2.jpg", 2.99),
  FoodModel("Chenese Dip", "Hawkers", "images/sushi.jpg", 4.99),
  FoodModel("Burgar", "KFC", "images/food2.jpg", 2.99),

 
];
```

Here is my food_model.dart file's code,

```
class FoodModel {
  String? name;
  String? brand;
  String? image;
  double? price;
  FoodModel(this.name, this.brand, this.image, this.price);
}
```

Here is my food_card_item.dart file's code,

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    class FoodCardItem extends StatelessWidget {
      late String? name;
      late String? brand;
      late String? imageUrl;
      late double? price;
      FoodCardItem(this.name, this.brand, this.imageUrl, this.price, {super.key});
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
        return Container(
          height: size.width / 2.5,
          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 10),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
            color: Colors.white,
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(color: Colors.black.withAlpha(100), blurRadius: 10.0),
            ],
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 5),
            child:
                Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, children: [
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    name!,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    brand!,
                    style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 15),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    price.toString(),
                    style: const TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontSize: 20,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Container(
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                child: Image.asset(imageUrl!),
              )
            ]),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
Here is my food_list_view.dart file's code,

    import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
    import 'package:lecture_7/UI/food_card_item.dart';
    import 'package:lecture_7/constants/food_const.dart';
    import 'package:lecture_7/model/food_model.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:pull_to_refresh/pull_to_refresh.dart';
    
    class FoodListView extends StatefulWidget {
      const FoodListView({super.key});
    
      @override
      State<FoodListView> createState() => _FoodListViewState();
    }
    
    class _FoodListViewState extends State<FoodListView> {
       RefreshController refreshController =
          RefreshController(initialRefresh: false,);
    
      int max_count = 10;
      List<FoodModel> foodList = [];
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        _initDataLoad();
      }
    
      void _getMoreList(int nextCount) {
        // print("Getting next items");
        for (int i = max_count; i < nextCount; i++) {
          foodList.add(FOODLIST[i]);
        }
        max_count = nextCount;
    
        setState(() {});
      }
    
      void _onRefreshList() {
        foodList.clear();
        setState(() {});
        _initDataLoad();
      }
    
      void _initDataLoad() {
        for (int i = 0; i < max_count; i++) {
          foodList.add(FOODLIST[i]);
        }
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        final Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
        return SafeArea(
          minimum: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
          child: Scaffold(
            body: SmartRefresher(
            
              enablePullDown: true,
              enablePullUp: true,
              physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    
              header: const WaterDropHeader(),
              controller: refreshController,
    
              footer: CustomFooter(
                builder: (BuildContext context,LoadStatus? mode) {
                Widget body = Container();
                if (mode == LoadStatus.loading) {
                  body = const CupertinoActivityIndicator();
                } else if (mode == LoadStatus.noMore) {
                  body =const Text("No More Data");
                }
                return Container(
                  height: 55.0,
                  child: Center(child: body),
                );
              }),
              onLoading: () {
                if (max_count == FOODLIST.length) {
                  refreshController.loadNoData();
                } else {
                  Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 1000), () {
                    _getMoreList(max_count + 10);
                    // Do somethings
                  });
                  refreshController.loadComplete();
                }
              },
              onRefresh: () {
                _onRefreshList();
                refreshController.refreshCompleted();
              },
              child: ListView.builder(
        
                itemCount: FOODLIST.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  
                  return FoodCardItem(
                    FOODLIST[index].name,
                    FOODLIST[index].brand,
                    FOODLIST[index].image,
                    FOODLIST[index].price,
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }

Here is the main.dart.
import 'package:lecture_7/UI/food_list_view.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: FoodListView(),
    );
  }
}
```